# File upload via PHP CurlFile failing from cron

Tags: php, curl, cron, upload

I have an 80M zip file that I am uploading to 'ShareFile' through their REST API using PHP cURL. The script works fine when run via the browser or on my local Windows machine using the php7 CLI. However when I attempt to run the script via a cron job on our client's shared hosting using `/usr/local/bin/ea-php71`, **the file and script suddenly stop running mid-upload**.

1. I have set my email address to be notified of any and all cron output.
2. I have a `set_error_handler` error handler that echoes any received errors and attempts to log them to a file (this never gets called).
3. I have a `register_shutdown_function` that also never gets called.
4. Finally, I have a `curl_setopt` `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` callback to see what is happening with the upload - it writes the total upload bytes `$uploadTotal` and the current upload bytes `$uploadCurrent` to a log along with a timestamp.
5. (Edit) - Forgot to mention I've also got the verbose setting enabled `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and am outputting stderr to a log file - but nothing relevant is displayed.

Number 4 has given me the most insight into the issue - when the script is run as a cron job the upload stops around:

`upload progress: [UploadTotal: 87455948] [UploadCurrent: 34913772]`

every time (roughly around 67 seconds).

Some final details ...

- When uploading the 80MB file through cron - my error handler and shutdown function never get called, nor does the cron email from any echoed data. The script just seems to simply PAUSE forever (it's almost like the script is waiting for user input or something).

However:

- If I run the script locally or change the upload file to a 5MB file - everything works as normal - all functions get called and I receive an email notifying that the script has finished running.

It looks to me like I'm hitting some kind of timeout through cron which, per everything I've read should not be the case. I'm looking for some ideas for what I could be running into or how to troubleshoot this one.

Thank you!

Comment: See this : https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115569

Comment: @Dilek - thanks for the comment, not sure what you're showing me though, can you be more specific why my upload might be stopping during a cronjob